# R apply cannot get multiple mins when rows exceed certain numbers

Tags: r, apply, min

I am trying to get a random variable when there are 2 minimal values, using a line of code like

```
sliced_coor$option<-apply(sliced_coor[1:312], 1, function(t) sample(names(t)[which(t==min(t[c('intuitive','reflective')]))],1))
```

I intend to apply for all rows, [1:312] is just where I found the abnormality. It is very strange that the function fails to get 2 minimal values once the rows exceed 312, and the limit is not constant when I tested with other data..

Although I managed to fix the issue with moving the specification of columns `[c('intuitive','reflective')]` to data parameter - `sliced_coor` , but I am still don't understand the problem of the early method.

Comment: What exactly is the structure of `sliced_coor`? If a dataframe, then `sliced_coor[1:312]` is similar to `sliced_coor[, 1:312]` meaning you are working on columns 1:312 rather than rows 1:312

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @Onyambu sliced_coor is a data.table, and [1:312] is surely rows (output confirmed), [c('intuitive','reflective')] are columns of int.